# AS3: Error loading playerglobal / airglobal.swc, for runtime inspection/reflection?

Tags: actionscript-3

In writing a code converter (AS3 to another language) it is necessary to get access to the entire inheritance chain from all custom classes, and from the AS3 core.

The converter itself is written in AIR, and the apps to be ported will be either Flash Player or AIR apps. This leaves me in something of a quandary: I will need to runtime-load a different version of either playerglobal or airglobal (as compared with that loaded for the converter itself!) for that *specific* app, in order to reflect on it. When my converter attempts to load library.swf (the SWF found inside playerglobal.swc), I am shown

`VerifyError: Error #1079: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code.`

This is problematic as until I overcome this, I cannot use `describeType()` to inspect the classes in the SWF. (And I would really rather avoid reading ABC from SWFs in order to get class information.)

Any solutions?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use describeType as-is? What exactly do you need the specific playerglobal or airglobal swc's for that you can't do already?

Comment: @Creynders See comment below Sean's answer.

Comment: Ah, yes it's a strictly incremental API, so if you make sure your converter uses the latest .swc's it shouldn't encounter any unknown as3/air classes or members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`playerglobal.swc` and `airglobal.swc` are mainly used for code hinting, and to let the compiler know what native methods are available.  They contain a few actual blocks of code, but mostly empty functions.  *You can't load them at run time*, and you can't override the native definitions anyway.

I'm confused about why you need to do this for introspection.  You should be able to use `describeType` on an instance of a native variable from your converter and get exactly the same output as if it were called from inside the app itself.

Comment: I'm assuming version differences. Having said that, every FP & AIR version is backward-compatible, so you may be right. But I am also not sure of the difference between AIR & FP in this regard. If airglobal contains everything that playerglobal provides, and more, then I can use the already-loaded airglobal.swc to happily do all my reflection. But if it _isn't_...

Comment: I'm pretty certain, but not 100% sure, that airglobal does NOT cover all classes in playerglobal. However, it does contain overrides, if I'm not mistaken, so you should make sure to check airglobal first and then if-not-already found move on to playerglobal

Comment: @Creynders thanks for the advice, it helps... But this would lead back to my original problem, which is that I cannot load playerglobal at runtime due to the error that is thrown. In order to avoid Loader (which seems to cause this problem) I have actually tried to load the swc's swf as bytecode using nochump's zip lib, and then pass the bytearray into as3-commons-bytecode in order to do some reflection. But sadly as3-commons-bytecode's load method for bytearray is bugged :/ If airglobal or playerglobal is loaded, I cannot seem to load another airglobal or playerglobal.

Comment: @SeanFujiwara I think you missed a key part of my question, which is "the apps to be ported will be either Flash Player or AIR apps." This means I need flexibility on loading in a different version of airglobal or playerglobal, as it may be different to the version that is implicitly loaded for the AIR-based converter app at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't too clear. If your app is an air app it will cover all classes, interfaces and members. No need to worry about the swc's.

Comment: @NickWiggill I didn't respond to that part of your question because it's irrelevant.  `playerglobal.swc` and `airglobal.swc` are not ever loaded to begin with, so it doesn't make sense to say you want to load a different one.  I'm not sure what problems you had with as3-commons-bytecode, but if you just want to parse the SWF, you can try my own project, SWFWire: http://www.swfwire.com/decompiler